# Tasker nodejs + mysql + php

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, task

I need something like tasker on php + mysql + nodejs.
So, client do some action and app (php) write it down in mysql table (innodb) (create the new task). After that nodejs will find new task and execute it.
And then, obviously, I need to remove or deactivate this task.

My question is what if I have too many clients (about 50-100thsd) and all of them are doing something constantly, as a result I'll get too many records in my table, and my auto_increment id will increase to a huge values. It's no good.
Tasks after execution does not irrelevant.

Has anyone done a similar project?
Maybe you have some advices for me.
Thank you and sorry for bad english!